# Por que NaN é maior que qualquer número?

Tags: javascript, nan

Um exemplo prático dessa afirmação é:

```
parseInt(50) > parseInt('a');
```

Ao executar essa operação em um console, por exemplo, o resultado é `false`.
O código real que me trouxe a essa questão é parecido com esse:

```
variableB = parseInt(jQuery('some-element').html());
if(parseInt(variableA) > variableB)
     // Faça isso.
else
     // Faça outra coisa.
```

As vezes o `some-element` não vai ser preenchido com absolutamente nada, causando o valor de `variableB` ser `NaN`. Mas como `some-element` não foi preenchido com nada, eu gostaria que fosse avaliado como se tivesse sido preenchido com 0. Ou seja, se `variableA` for um positivo maior que 0, a comparação deveria retornar `true`.

Comment: Você poderia colocar uma condição com NaN ou apenas um 'e' no if

Comment: Pergunta no SO inglês -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982881/why-nan-is-greater-than-any-number-in-javascript

Comment: Não seria bom colocar a referência do link na própria pergunta?

Answer (score 4):

Com base na pergunta do SO Inglês que você "*copiou*"

Edit -

Com base na pergunta do SO Inglês que você "**fez lá e aqui**"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982881/why-nan-is-greater-than-any-number-in-javascript

Verificações com NaN sempre dão FALSE.

NaN não é maior que nenhum número

NaN não é igual que nenhum número

NaN não é menor que nenhum número

Apenas a verificação booleana será false.

Comment: Ah, então assim sim.

Comment: Ééééééé José!!!!! Ta certo!

Comment: [Introduzindo conteúdo relevante ao site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2171/1544), [Perfil de Pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4285/stack-overflow-perfil-de-pergunta) e [Geração de Conteúdo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115/%C3%89-util-fazer-perguntas-que-geram-conte%C3%BAdo-para-a-net)